# trigger for a compostite key and update another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `threads` and `threadreply`.

`threads` has a composite primary key, `(thread_id,reply_id)`.

When I insert a new row into `threadreply`, I need to:

- update my column `threads.reply_count` by adding +1 to the previous value; and
- insert data into `threadreply` by adding +1 to the `MAX(reply_id)` with same `thread_id`.

Using the following trigger, I was able to add+1 to my `reply_id`, but couldn't get to update my `reply_count`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addone BEFORE INSERT ON threadreply
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.reply_id = (
        SELECT IFNULL(
            (
                SELECT MAX(reply_id) + 1
                FROM   threadreply
                WHERE  thread_id = NEW.thread_id
            ),
            1
        )
    );
END
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: innoDB and thanks for the question edit .

Comment: If you want to update, then some update command is needed. Have you tried `UPDATE threads SET reply_count = reply_count +1 WHERE threads.id = NEW.thread_id` ?

Comment: @kordirko ya individually both statements work but i am unable to get both the statements work in the same trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there is a typo in the question and the composite key `(thread_id,reply_id)` exists in the `threadreply` table, not in the `threads` table.

The trigger might look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addone BEFORE INSERT ON threadreply
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.reply_id = (
        SELECT IFNULL(
            (
                SELECT MAX(reply_id) + 1
                FROM   threadreply
                WHERE  thread_id = NEW.thread_id
            ), 1
        )
    );
    UPDATE threads SET reply_count = reply_count + 1
    WHERE thread_id = NEW.thread_id;
END
/
```

Take a look at this demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e7bb/2

The trigger and insert statements are on the left side in the `schema` window, below are shown results of the demo.